# How to set updated object in first position - Mongo DB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this object and query

**Object**

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: 'John Smith',
  items: [{
     name: 'item 1',
     value: 'one',
     _id: 1
  },{
     name: 'item 2'
     value: 'two',
     _id: 2,
  }]
}
```

**Query**

```
Person.update({'items._id': 2}, {'$set': {
    'items.$.surname': 'new surname'

}}, function(err) { ...
```

I want that the new updated (key / value) to be setted on first position like this

```
,{
         surname: 'new surname',
         name: 'item 2'
         value: 'two',
         _id: 2,
      }
```

not like this

```
 ,{

             name: 'item 2',
             value: 'two',
             _id: 2,
             surname: 'new surname',

          }
```

So is there a solution,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know if you append a property to an object that wasn't previously there it will always be appended to the object. The only workaround is to set the surname in the object to start with.